# How to configure ftp server in GCP VM instance?

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform, ftp

I installed wordpress in a GCP VM and tried installing plugins and themes through the `wp-admin` dashboard, but it asks for an FTP server.

I installed `vsftp` but couldn't connect to the server, even after creating firewall rules. I was hoping someone could help.

Comment: What instructions/recipe did you follow to install the FTP server?  Are you sure the server is running?  What firewall rules did you change/setup?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example.

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2):

As other have pointed out, knowing what type of firewall rules (and how) you have configured or if you followed a specific tutorial would be very helpful to provide a specific answer. I'll do my best to provide a general answer based on the details you shared.

It's not clear to me if you modified the firewall rules inside your instance or in the [Cloud Console](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls?hl=nl#firewall_rules_in). [This page](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) describes the commands for working with firewall rules in GCP and offers some examples in using them. In case you were setting firewall rules within the instance, make sure both firewalls are configured properly.

I'm not familiar with *vsftp* but I found [this tutorial](https://zatackcoder.com/how-to-setup-ftp-server-vsftpd-on-google-cloud-compute-engine/) that you may find helpful as it's specific for GCP.

As Gurpreet mentioned in his reply, you can use SSH keys to connect via SFTP instead. [This is a tutorial](https://www.onepagezen.com/google-cloud-ftp-filezilla-quick-start/) to configure an SFTP connection with Filezilla and is also specific to GCP.

If you expanded your question with more details, screenshots, etc. maybe we could provide better suggestions to solve your issue.

Comment: SFTP would be the easiest method for GCP environment

Answer (score -1):

You can use filezilla to connect to GCP through SFTP.

Web Host is your public IP
Username should be root by default unless you changed it
And, Password is your root password.

If you don't have the root password or not able to connect via SFTP You can use SSH keys.

Read this carefully regarding how to add SSH keys in Google Cloud Console:

```
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys
```

After adding SSH keys, you can Filezilla without root password using SSH keys

```
https://tecadmin.net/import-private-key-in-filezilla/
```